# auto replace variable in string with laravel

Tags: php, laravel

There is any clear method to string replace like this

```
echo some_clean_mehod('Hi name: .you have wallet: dollar in your wallet. your register date is created_at:',$user);
```

and show

```
Hi John. you have 100 dollar in your wallet. your register date is 2020-01-10
```

**I know there are many ways in php but i wanna Know there is any built-in laravel method ?**

Comment: This is a translation feature: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/localization#replacing-parameters-in-translation-strings - use the framework's features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this (in :

```
'msg' => 'Hi :name .you have :wallet dollar in your wallet. your register date is :created_at'
```

And than:

```
echo Lang::get('messages.msg', ['name' => $userName, 'wallet ' => $amount, 'created_at' => $createdAt]);
```

You could also probably do it like this (not tested):

```
$user = [
'name' => $userName,
'wallet' => $amount,
'created_at' => $createdAt
];
```

And:

```
echo Lang::get('messages.msg', $user);
```

Also, whatever you pass in, is not a problem, you can pass full user, and use only fildes you need, but be carefull that what is defined in translation is also passed in.

See more here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/localization

Answer (score -1):

You can write your own :

```
 $user = [
    'name:' => 'John',
    'wallet:' => 100,
    'created_at:' => '2020-01-10'
];


function some_clean_mehod($str,$replace_vars){
    $keys = array_keys($replace_vars);
    $values = array_values($replace_vars);
    return str_replace($keys, $values, $str);
}

echo some_clean_mehod('Hi name: .you have wallet: dollar in your wallet. your register date is created_at:',$user);
```

Comment: Why do it like this, when Laravel already supports translations and variables in translations out of the box?